# How to move SSL certificate to another EC2 Win 2008 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

We have an EC2 Windows 2008 instance that crashed and would not reboot.  We have now rebuilt the instance.  We had an Entrust cert on that instance and need to move the cert to the new instance.  How can we do this?

Thanks

Sean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would have to either restore the certificate from a backup or have it re-issued. I would check with Entrust and see what they can do.

Comment: I'd second this. Many SSL certificate providers now allow re-issuing certificates without extra cost and will do so in minutes, so absent a ready backup of the key and certificate this is probably the fastest fix as well.

Comment: Thanks Greg and Jeremy, much appreciated.  It turns our that this is what we had to do.  It took nearly an extra day to do this as they repeat some of their identity checks (of course!) and they are 6 hours behind us, being in Dallas.